# Number to Date - Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, nscalendar

Getting the day of year is straightforward, e.g.

```
func dayOfYear(inputDate:NSDate) -> (Int) {
    let cal         = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let returnDay   = cal.ordinalityOfUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, inUnit: .CalendarUnitYear, forDate: inputDate)
    return returnDay
}
```

But how do you do the reverse? It would obviously return just the day/month. I can easily write a tedious routine back-calculating but is there a smart way?

Comment: Take a look at `dateFromComponents(:)` on NSCalendar. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateFromComponents:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `NSCalendar` provides a way to coalesce calendar components into a single date object. Take a look at this example I wrote in a Playground:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

let inputDate: NSDate = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let day = calendar.ordinalityOfUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, inUnit: .CalendarUnitYear, forDate: inputDate)

let components = NSDateComponents()
components.day = day

let date = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)
```

According to the documentation,

> When there are insufficient components provided to completely specify an absolute time, a calendar uses default values of its choice. When there is inconsistent information, a calendar may ignore some of the components parameters or the method may return nil. Unnecessary components are ignored (for example, Day takes precedence over Weekday and Weekday ordinals).

Furthermore,

> Note that some computations can take a relatively long time to perform.

See the [NSCalendar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateFromComponents:) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
func dayOfYear(inputDate: NSDate) -> Int {
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().ordinalityOfUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, inUnit: .CalendarUnitYear, forDate: inputDate)
}

func dateFromDayOfYear(day: Int) -> NSDate {
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: NSDate()), month: 1, day: day, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
}

let numberOfDays = dayOfYear(NSDate())   // 195

dateFromDayOfYear(numberOfDays)    // "Jul 14, 2015, 12:00 AM"
```